# ggplot2 - Overlay Mean of Each Group

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to mimic this lattice plot using ggplot.  The data for this plot is `lme4::Dyestuff`.

[image]

I am able to plot each of the points in a similar manner, but I am unable to plot the line which represents the mean of each batch.

```
library (lme4)
library (ggplot2)

ggplot (Dyestuff, aes (Yield, Batch, colour = Batch)) + geom_jitter ()
```

Q. How can I add this line using ggplot?  Notice also how the batches on the y-axis are ordered by the mean yield of the batch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use `Batch` as x values and `Yield` as y values. Line is added with `stat_summary()` and argument `fun.y=mean` to get mean value of Yield. Then `coord_flip()` is used to get `Batch` as y axis. To change order of `Batch` values you can use `reorder()` function inside the `aes()` of `ggplot()`.

```
ggplot (Dyestuff, aes (reorder(Batch,Yield), Yield)) + geom_jitter(aes(colour=Batch))+ 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="line",aes(group=1))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]